# OpenELEC: Bootstrap GCC with libatomic

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, atomic, openelec, ci20

I am trying to bootstrap GCC during OpenELEC compilation. I need to add `libatomic` for the target system so as to compile some packages.

When I try to add `libatomic` for the target system, I get a compilation error with:

```
/home/mathieu/tmp/OpenELEC.tv/build.OpenELEC-ci20.mips-8.0-devel/toolchain/mipsel-openelec-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/home/mathieu/tmp/OpenELEC.tv/build.OpenELEC-ci20.mips-8.0-devel/toolchain/mipsel-openelec-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/home/mathieu/tmp/OpenELEC.tv/build.OpenELEC-ci20.mips-8.0-devel/toolchain/mipsel-openelec-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using the following `package.mk` file:

- https://github.com/malaterre/OpenELEC.tv/blob/fd5a5558104ed38aee1c53bb6d31ba73e8eb6e57/packages/lang/gcc/package.mk

If that matter I am targetting a MIPS system, specifically the [Creator CI20](http://elinux.org/MIPS_Creator_CI20):

- https://github.com/malaterre/OpenELEC.tv/blob/master/config/arch.mips

I am not clear about the OpenELEC build system, but it seems as if the host compiler and target compiler are build at the same time, while I would need to build [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) in between:

- http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was not hard at all. Basically one need to create first a minimal gcc (bootstrap) and then build the full one with `libatomic`:

- https://github.com/malaterre/OpenELEC.tv/blob/70dbe25c1647f01eb83c108939c470437a2db259/packages/lang/gcc/package.mk

Answer (score 2):

You might need to have a GCC built without libatomic to build one with libatomic. The intermediary compiler will serve to build your CRT (if you do not have it already) and libatomic, so that a second compiler can use these "prebuilt" things.